# Installing Nvidia driver not from bionic repositories

Tags: drivers, nvidia, matlab

I'm wanting to upgrade my Nvidia driver to the latest version from the Nvidia website (390.77) because the version currently in the bionic repos (390.48) has a known bug that causes my version of MATLAB to crash. Looking at the documentation for installing from the Nvidia website I don't know everything involved and am worried installing will ruin things on my computer. What are the risk involved going with drivers not in the official repositories and do you think I might have any problems installing the latest version? Or is there a way to get a more updated version somewhere in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: driver PPA is good solution

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Comment: I haven't heard of those, I'll give it a try.

Comment: So it looks like the bionic repositories just updated their Nvidia drivers to 390.77 so no need even to add the ppa